# Android - How to store an extra hidden information(s) (by tag) in layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-layout-weight

I have a layout like this-

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <!-- Linearlaout which acts as ListView in this case -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/Main_View_Reference"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        android:contentDescription="This is a container reference for main list items"

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

And another layout for inflating the "LinearLayout" part of this layout like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:id="@+id/Level_3_Layout"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Level_3_Item_Name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        android:text="Itame Name"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Level_3_Item_Price"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        android:text="Item Price"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="13sp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

</LinearLayout>
```

What I want to do is I want to assign a tag value for the dynamic inflated layouts created from second part.

So, I want to set extra hidden information for each created (inflated) layout with Java to store some extra information so that I can retrive them in next time when I need them like HTML's hidden field.

Is there any way in android?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Create your own class to hold all the data you need plus the layout?

Comment: why not using `View.setTag` method?

Comment: I want to set tag for layout, not for views. Views will not fulfil my purpose because therer is multi level view. So I need to set tag for layout. Is it possible?

Comment: dude, `Layout` is also a `View` so u can also use setTag for Layout

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not rally sure what did you mean by 'dynamic', but I assume you want to assign not just the value, but also the key for that 'hidden field' of yours.
If my assumptions is correct, then you could utilize this method:

```
yourView.setTag(int id, Object object);
```

I know you're reluctant to use `setTag` but in this use case, I think it is the most suited thing to do. Do note the `int id` though, using that you could assign as may tag as you want (as long they all possess different id) thus making it pretty dynamic.
Should you want to retrieve a tag you had assigned using the aforementioned method, you call this:

```
yourView.getTag(int id);
```

Hope this helps!

If this is still not what you wanted, I'm afraid the only option would be to extend your desired `View` and then customizing it to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

For layouts use `android:tag=""`, e.g.

```
....
<View 
    android:tag="YOUR_HIDDEN_THINGIE"
    .../>
```

Comment: No, I wanted it to be  dynamic. So it is not what I want. Thanks for answering

Answer (score 1):

or after you have called your view

```
View v = findViewBy(R.id.myview);// could be any view widget
v.setTag(myobject);
```

also note that when you use android:tag in layout, when your layout is inflated your `Tag` will persist, and you can retrieve it by `v.getTag()`

Comment: Ha ha. You are giving answer seeing from the comments. Funny.

It is not what I wanted

Comment: lol,funny i didnt see it sir, but this is the only way aside from the other answer, and you can always change programmatically, by the same method@AbrarJahin and you are welcomed sir